# ecryptfs-recover-private not accepting password

Tags: password, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I'm trying to recover my encrypted home directory using an ubuntu liveUSB. When I run ecryptfs-recover-private and it asks for my login passphrase, I type my login passphrase, and it fails. In /var/log/syslog, it says incorrect wrapping key. Before I lost access, my laptop lost power suddenly, so I'm not sure whether there's any corruption going on here.

When it says LOGIN passphrase, I assume it means my most recent passphrase, is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not incorrect (too many negatives...). To unwrap your `wrapped-passphrase` file you need the last user login passphrase that was used to encrypt/"wrap" it.

If your user passphrase was changed without you being logged in, through a live or root user, or if something went wrong then you might need a previous login passphrase.

Or, if you used the `ecryptfs-migrate-home` script yourself or saw the warning somewhere, you really should have a **backup copy of the mount passphrase**. You can use it to decrypt your files without knowing the login passphrase. The `ecryptfs-recover-private` script should ask you for the mount passphrase if you don't have the login passphrse.